# Pyintaller error when a running exe (aplication) creates another exe file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have an option in an app that would create another exe on the desktop using the pyinstaller library, it works when the app is executed from the .py file it works perfectly, however when I create a onefile or onedir executable with pyinstaller, it will just dont work. This is the code:

```
import os, shutil, sys
import PyInstaller.__main__

#acces icon with the file on onefile mode

datafile = "icon.ico"
if not hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
    datafile = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), datafile)
else:
    datafile = os.path.join(sys.prefix, datafile)


def resource_path(relative_path):    
    try:       
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")
        
    
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

#creating the file .py file for creating the exe 

if a != '' and b != '':
            if self.option_var.get():
                with open('sa3k3lkd32.py', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(...)


#setting the options and creating the exe 

options = ['--name=' + 'sa3k3lkd32', '--onefile', '--clean', '--noconfirm', '--icon={}'.format(resource_path(datafile))]
PyInstaller.__main__.run(['sa3k3lkd32.py'] + options)



#unistalling temporary files when creating exe and moving to desktop

os.remove(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sa3k3lkd32.py'))
shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'build'))
                
                
shutil.move(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'dist', 'sa3k3lkd32.exe'), os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop','{} Save.exe'.format(a)))
                
shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'dist'))
os.remove(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sa3k3lkd32.spec'))
```

When the new file is supposed to be created, a new tkinter window equal to the original is opened, and the original freeze. I set the notwindowd mode to see what is happening, and when the copy of the main window is closed this displays on the console:
[the error that happen when closing new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omB7s.png)

I tried to comment parts of the code and when I comment this line:

```
PyInstaller.__main__.run(['sa3k3lkd32.py'] + options)
```

The new window would not be created. So the problem is in that line, the problem is that I dont know how to solve it.

I tried to look in the internet for the first exception, but I didn't find anything that made the trick. I also add the icon file, when creating the exe file with --add-data.

Answer (score 0):

pyinstaller need to pack the environment into the executable, but when it is executing inside the executable and not your original python environment it doesn't have access to many of the dependencies needed create the executable, including pyinstaller itself ....

so what should you do ?

you need to package and ship the `environment` itself that will be used to create the executable, and have that be the one to create your executables, you can't just ship executables that will build other executables, (it's possible, but not something you can do with pyinstaller)

Comment: what do you mean by enviroment, im not a very experinced programmer.